# Snap to road in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have GPS System that trace venhcles. I use openlayer to display their routes via vector layers with lines and when my gps tracking device didn't send me position in curve (turn). The line is going outside the road. I want to use snap to road to fix it, but I Didn't found any solution in OpenLayers. Can you help me with some solution.

I want to make something like: http://www.cyclelicio.us/2013/strava-snap-tool-gps/

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very specific to OpenLayers, but the technique of snapping a trajectory to a road network is called [map-matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching). [OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api#map-matching) and [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching) offer open-source implementations of that algorithm that you might want to take a look at.